# Display name in Active Directory is not being updated properly

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, rename

When you search for a Name in Active Directory:

[image: When you search a Name in active directory:]

When you double click on the searched name you will see that the attribute "display name" is not the same as the name you searched:

[image: When you double click on the searched name you will see that the attribute "display name" is not the same as the name you searched:]

I have written this code to update the user's "Display Name":

```
if (aduser.DisplayName != null && aduser.DisplayName.Trim().Length > 0)
{
    existingUser.Rename("cn=" + aduser.DisplayName);                               
    existingUser.CommitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to Rename the DirectoryEntry object itself, then Rename method will do the trick. But, if you need to change the display name of the account, this does not work.

If you look at the definition of Rename method, it says,

```
Changes the name of this System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry object.
```

and it does not change the Display Name. Following snippet will update the User object's DisplayName using PrincipalContext and UserPrincipal.

```
    string userNameToUpdate = "userNameToLookup";
    string modifiedDisplayName = "cn=NewName in Display";

    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Name, userNameToUpdate);
    user.DisplayName = modifiedDisplayName;
    user.Save();
```

If you are interested in using the DirectoryEntry, then you have to update the value of the property for that UserObject.

```
    existingUser.Properties["displayname"].Value = "cn=YourNewValue";
    existingUser.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: You probably wouldn't want the `cn=` in the `displayName`.

Comment: I'll leave that on the OP to set whatever he wants, I am providing the methods that should help anyone for updating user property

Comment: @KUNALMEHTA does this help?